# Liferay private messaging portlet along with message boards portlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-6

I have noticed that the private messaging portlet uses MBMessageLocalServiceUtil method getMBMessage(long id) where id is
mbThreadId which is a property of private messaging portlet basic entity(UserThread). So, when there is no record in message boards entries with id
that corresponds to mbThreadId an exception is thrown

```
10:15:06,232 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-2][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.NoSuchMessageException: No MBMessage exists with the primary key 111020
at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.persistence.MBMessagePersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(MBMessagePersistenceImpl.java:19490)
at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.persistence.MBMessagePersistenceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(MBMessagePersistenceImpl.java:19508)
at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.base.MBMessageLocalServiceBaseImpl.getMBMessage(MBMessageLocalServiceBaseImpl.java:291)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
...
```

Is this a normal behavior? Can these 2 portlets work together?

Comment: What do you mean with "work together"? If PM uses the storage of MB,  I'd hope that it's been designed with the continued operation of MB in mind. If you've manually removed the data from the tables, they will be missing, and I'd consider failure a normal behaviour. If you didn't mess with the database - not so much. Please give more information.

Comment: What I mean is that PM uses the storage of MB but only for getting messages. So when I create a new private message, this is stored successfully in PM table but there is no respective record created in MB storage. This results in the above exception, as the view_messages jsp of PM tries to get a message from MB board which has the id of the record that was created in PM table.

Comment: I tested that with a clean database. In the beginning, no records exist  both in PM and MB tables.

Comment: In that case it looks like a bug worth reporting (or searching if it has been reported already) on https://issues.liferay.com/ - please give version numbers of both Liferay and the private messaging portlet (I hope it's the latest Liferay/plugin version, otherwise I'd recommend to upgrade first, then retry).